# 'Missing "key" prop for element' error but i implemented a key in my loop. What missing?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I believe that I give a unique key to each `<td>` and `<tr>`

The full code of my component is below:

```
export default function TableComponent( data: any ) {
    const columnNames = Object.keys(data.data);
    const rowIndices = Object.keys(data.data[columnNames[0]])
        
        type rowProps = {
            idx: number;
        }
        const CustomRow = ({ idx }: rowProps) => {
            return (
                <tr key={idx}>
                    {columnNames.map((columnName, index) => (
                        <td key={`${index}+${idx}`}> {data.data[columnName][idx]} </td>
                    ))}
                </tr>
            )
        }
        
        return (        
            <table className="table table-striped">
                <tbody>
                    {rowIndices.map((row,index) => (
                        <CustomRow 
                            idx={row}
                        />
                    ))}
            </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    };
```

I get this error:

Missing "key" prop for element in iterator

Which is generated by on this part

```
                <tbody>
                    {rowIndices.map((row,index) => (
                        <CustomRow 
                            idx={row}
                        />
                    ))}
```

Comment: `<CustomRow key={row}`

Comment: Yes that solved it! let me mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You need to put a key on the second map:

````
        <table className="table table-striped">
                <tbody>
                    {rowIndices.map((row,index) => (
                        <CustomRow 
                          key={`unique key ${index}`}
                            idx={row}
                        />
                    ))}
            </tbody>
            </table>
    ```
````